# Extension Method with MemberwiseClone

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have ApiContext object (do not have the code) and would like to make extention method for it

what is wrong with the code? it says:

> cannot use this in static member

`ApiContext` resides in the Singleton Pattern

```
public sealed class EbayProxySdk
{
    private static EbayProxySdk _instance = null;
    private static readonly Object LockObj = new object();

    public ApiContext Context;
.
.
.
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static ApiContext DeepClone(this ApiContext context)
    {
        ApiContext other = (ApiContext)this.MemberwiseClone();
        return other;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** what I am eventually trying to do is Deep Clone to `ApiContext` which is a complex object with nested objects

Comment: You might be looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `MemberwiseClone` from outside the class because it is a `protected` method. If you could do that than anyone could call any protected method which is not in the spirit of access protection. Can't be done.

You can use (full trust) reflection to do this or you can make the class `ApiContext` cooperate by exposing a `public` method that does what you want.

Comment: Can you please share code example how can Deep Clone this object? it has nested objects inside as well

Comment: I will not write your code for you but I'll help you with any concrete problems. Did you understand what I said in this answer?

Comment: But that's not the reason why his code is failing, is it? The reason is that he is trying to access `this` in static context which is impossible.

Comment: @zespri there is no good workaround. Even if he changes this to context he gains nothing. It's just a different error message.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you cannot use `this` in a static method. Use the variable you named context:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static ApiContext DeepClone(this ApiContext context)
    {
        ApiContext other = (ApiContext)context.MemberwiseClone();
        return other;
    }
}
```

Comment: now it sais 'cannot access protected method MemberWiseClone here'

Comment: Then you cannot call it. An extension method cannot do anything special, you cannot access methods or fields you would not normally have access to. Extension methods are just syntactic sugar, they do not break the access modifier rules.

Comment: Can you please share code example how can Deep Clone this object? it has nested objects inside as well

Comment: @user829174 There is no single best way to do this. Maybe you want to ask another question from here, with more info about how this object looks like? Does it implement IClonable? ISerializable? DataContract? None of the above?

Comment: Maybe it's easier to create a second one from parameters the first can deliver, than clone it? You need to provide the object description. My guess would be that you are trying to solve an XY problem. This object does not seem to support deep cloning in any way. Maybe that's for a reason. If you are the first and only programmer that needs to deep clone it, maybe the others chose a different way?